# how to simplify the data from a multiple same variables for a record in python?

Tags: python-3.x, data-analysis, data-science

I have a data as below:
time(in min)

Time  |Parameters  |values
0:00      |record id      |1     
0:00      |name                |abc   
0:00      |age                    |12    
1:00      |a                         |44    
2:00      |b                        |18    
3:00      |a                         |46    
4:00      |k                         |19    
0:00      |record id      |2     
0:00      |name                |sdf   
0:00      |age                   |18    
1:00      |a                         |39    
2:00      |b                         |19    
3:00      |k                         |16

I want to get a clean format for analysing the data. how to get parameter variables as the column header with respect to time ?

I am writing a python code and i tried groupby time but not able to process further.

I want to further pass this to an algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Use `str.split('|')` to split a string into multiple parts and use `str.strip()` to remove leading & trailing whitespaces.

```
data='''Time  |Parameters  |values
0:00   |record id      |1 
0:00   |name           |abc 
0:00   |age              |12 
1:00   |a                  |44 
2:00   |b                  |18 
3:00   |a                  |46 
4:00   |k                  |19 
0:00   |record id      |2 
0:00   |name           |sdf 
0:00   |age              |18 
1:00   |a                  |39 
2:00   |b                  |19 
3:00   |k                  |16 '''

for line in data.split('\n'):
    rows=[row.strip() for row in line.split('|')]
    print(rows)
```

The output is:

```
['Time', 'Parameters', 'values']
['0:00', 'record id', '1']
['0:00', 'name', 'abc']
['0:00', 'age', '12']
['1:00', 'a', '44']
['2:00', 'b', '18']
['3:00', 'a', '46']
['4:00', 'k', '19']
['0:00', 'record id', '2']
['0:00', 'name', 'sdf']
['0:00', 'age', '18']
['1:00', 'a', '39']
['2:00', 'b', '19']
['3:00', 'k', '16']
```

Is this what you are looking for?